# Swift How to segue indexPath value from CollectionviewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uisplitviewcontroller

I want to be able to reload the value in my `DetailViewController.` How do I segue the selected indexPath so I can call the value in the next view controller?

In my `didSelectItemAt` I have:

```
let monsters: Monsters!

let mons: [Monsters] = Data().mons
monsters = mons[indexPath.row] 

self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "DetailVC", sender: monsters)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a `monster` property in `DetailViewController`, and then assign it when you call `prepare(for segue:)`

```
// This would be a property at the top of DetailViewController
var monster:Monster?
```

Then inside the VC that performs the segue, create a property for `selectedMonster` to assign based on `indexPath`:

```
var selectedMonster:Monster?
```

Then when you user selects a cell:

```
selectedMonster = mons[indexPath.row]
```

In this same VC, this method would be called when the `performSegue(withIdentifier:)` gets called:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "DetailVC" {
        let detailVC = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
        detailVC.monster = selectedMonster
    }
}
```

You may want to check how you call `performSegue(withIdentifier:)`, usually you want the sender to be `self`, i.e. :

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "DetailVC", sender: self)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This has been bothering me for ages